# Linq To entities, Select from select

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have tried for sum time now but I cant get the hold of doing this selection in LINQ to Entites? How can I do a **Select on a Selection**?

```
SELECT * FROM tProduct AS tpp, tProductGroupDetail AS tppg,
    (SELECT tpgd.ProductGroupID AS pgID 
     FROM tProduct AS tp, tProductGroupDetail AS tpgd
     WHERE tp.ProductID = 428 AND tpgd.ProductID = tp.ProductID) AS JoinedTable
WHERE JoinedTable.pgID = tppg.ProductGroupID
      AND tpp.ProductID = tppg.ProductGroupID
```

Comment: .Any will do a subselect in your LINQ query.

Comment: Are you sure you need that subquery at all?

Comment: I dont have the ProductGroupID in my tProduct table so ill have to fetch it first?

Comment: If you are using Entity Framework, talk about Entities and Associations and not about tables!

I think your model is composed of two entities: Product and ProductGroup.

An association connects products and product groups. Each group is associated with several products. Each product is associated with several groups. It is therefore a many-to-many association. This kind of association is implemented as a table. This is the role of the table tProductGroupDetail.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the list of ProductGroup containing the product #428, just write:

```
dataContext.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == 428).ProductGroups
```

This solution assumes the existence in the entity `Product` of the navigation property `ProductGroups`. If this is not the case, thank you to specify the entity model.

Comment: I don't think `IQueryable<Product>` will have `ProductGroups` property

Comment: @sergey Yes, you're right! I just corrected the expression that now uses the FirstOrDefault operator instead of Where

Answer (score 3):

Your SQL statement is very bizarre. Isn't it equivalent to the following statement?

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    tProduct AS p
    INNER JOIN tProductGroupDetail AS pgd
        ON p.ProductID = pgd.ProductGroupID
WHERE
    pgd.ProductID = 428
```

The corresponding LINQ query would then be rather obvious.

---

Let's change your SQL step by step:

The nested SELECT looks like this:

```sql
(SELECT tpgd.ProductGroupID AS pgID 
FROM tProduct AS tp, tProductGroupDetail AS tpgd
WHERE tp.ProductID = 428 AND tpgd.ProductID = tp.ProductID)
```

This is the same as

```sql
(SELECT tpgd.ProductGroupID AS pgID 
FROM tProductGroupDetail AS tpgd
WHERE tpgd.ProductID = 428)
```

Since `tpgd.ProductID = tp.ProductID` you can directly directly test for `tpgd.ProductID = 428` without having to join with `tp`. The simplyfied statement now looks like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tProduct AS tpp, tProductGroupDetail AS tppg,
    (SELECT ProductGroupID
     FROM tProductGroupDetail
     WHERE ProductID = 428) AS JoinedTable
WHERE JoinedTable.ProductGroupID = tppg.ProductGroupID
      AND tpp.ProductID = tppg.ProductGroupID
```

Basically, what it does, is to join `tProduct` with `tProductGroupDetail`. The purpose of the additional join with `JoinedTable` is to restrict the records to contain only product groups having a `ProductID = 428`. This condition can be applied directly:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tProduct AS tpp, tProductGroupDetail AS tppg,
WHERE tppg.ProductID = 428 -- Note: ProductID of tggp, NOT tpp!
     AND tpp.ProductID = tppg.ProductGroupID
```

The last step is to replace the join with an `INNER JOIN` clause and to tweak the aliases. This yields my first SQL statement.

Comment: This gives me one product, the query above gives me 3 products

Comment: Have you tested `tProductGroupDetail.ProductID = 428` (which is correct) or `tProduct.ProductID = 428` (which is wrong)?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it (although it's off the top of my head, not tested):

```
var product = Products.Where(x => x.ProductGroup.Any(y => y.ProductID == 428));
```

Comment: I dont have productGroupID present in my Products table